# VBA // How to convert #N/A with specific Name or Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data in below form

```
City Name - City Code
Delhi     - DEL
Mumbai -  #N/A
Chennai - #N/A
```

there are N numbers of data, and want to replace #n/a value with city name. Ex. in 2nd row #n/a will be replaced by Mumbai and in 3rd row with chennai. 
Please advise.

Comment: Are the `#N/A` an error as a result of a formula in the cell?

Comment: yes, it is a error. but i have converted in to TEXT using paste special.

Comment: Well before you do that, wrap the formula in an IFERROR() that deals with the error.

Comment: i used the below code :  Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A2")
For Each cell In rng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cell) Then
        
        cell.value = 0
    End If
Next    this code is converting #n/a value with "0" but i want to replace it with specific city name.

Comment: Please put any code attempt in the original question using [edit] instead of in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is placed in columns A and B accordingly, below code will work for your problem:

```
Sub errors()
i = 1
Do Until ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = ""
If Left(CStr(Range("B" & i).Value2), 5) = "Error" Then Range("B" & i) = Range("A" & i).Value
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Attach data from the row on which you've got an error.

Comment: Sorry Adam I dint get. Please repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your data is in columns **A** and **B** and the values in column **A** are **constants**:

```
Sub fixup()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(r.Offset(0, 1).Text, "#N/A") > 0 Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: if possible please help me out i am using the code Sub jk()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 1
For iCntr = lRow To 10000 Step 1
If Cells(iCntr, 1) = "Jambi ,ID" Then
Rows(iCntr).Delete
End If

Next
End Sub
                 data  Jakarta ,ID
Jakarta ,ID
Jakarta ,ID
Jakarta ,ID
Jambi ,ID
Jambi ,ID
Jakarta ,ID
Jakarta ,ID
Jambi ,ID
Yangon ,MM
Yangon ,MM
Jambi ,ID
Jambi ,ID
Jambi ,ID
Yangon ,MM
Yangon ,MM
"Code delete the whole row where data is "Jambi ,ID" , but for example for loop delete 3rd row and 4th row become 3rd. hence how can be again delete 3rd row?